# Notation for the smallest number in a set?

Tags: notation

Let's assume I have a set like $S = \{2,1,3,4,8,10\}$.

What's the math notation for the smallest number in the set?

Comment: $\min(s)$ is what I would expect to see, given that the set has a smallest number.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The notation you looking for is:
$$\min$$

Suppose you have a ordinary finite set $A=\{a_1,\ldots,a_k\}$, then you can write the minimum notation as follows:

$$\min\{a_1,\ldots,a_k\}$$

In your case,

$$\min\{2,1,3,4,8,10\}=1$$

In case of functions, you can represent its minimum over a set as follows:
$$\min_{x\in S}f(x).$$

An example:

$$S=\mathbb{R},\ f(x)=x^2\Rightarrow \min_{x\in S}f(x)=0.$$

Look the comments above for more informations.

Comment: Note that a set being infinite certainly does not mean that $\min$ becomes invalid. Consider for example the natural numbers, which certainly have a least element. In the cases where $\min$ is not well-defined and $\inf$ would be more commonly used, one cannot really speak of the least element of a set, and so $\inf$ seems not applicable to this question.

Comment: @qaphla Thank you for the comment, I edited the answer.

Comment: I don't think anyone does write “$\displaystyle{\min_{x\in S}}$”. I would more readily believe “$\displaystyle{\min_{x\in S} f(x)}$”. Can you point to a published example of this?

Comment: @MJD Thank you for the comment I edited the answer. The notation that you pointed out is used for represent the minimum value of a function.

Comment: I had forget to accept. I'm really sorry

Answer (score 3):

In general for a given set $S$ which is nonempty and a subset of an ordered field we define the smallest element in the set to be the element $x \in S$ such that $x\leq y, \ \forall y \in S$. Since you said in a set, I will not introduce the notion of inf. I hope this helps.